# Django change foreign keys to BigInt

Tags: django, postgresql, model, foreign-keys, biginteger

I have two models (store and products) the primary key in both are BigInt but the relation column in products (store_id) is still integer. I dont want to use raw sql, how can I fix this issue using django?

Example:

```
class Product:
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
  store = models.ForeignKey(
          to='stores.Store', on_delete=models.CASCADE
      )

class Store:
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

store_id in model Products is still data type integer

Comment: I think you need more information here...  Can you not just change the database so they match types?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TimTisdall I could change the database directly but this is a big application and could take alot of time. I would rather use Django to programmatically fix the issue in case it comes up again.

Comment: Ah. You're trying to fix Django making the ForeignKey the wrong type?  I'm surprised it's not taking the type from the primary key column. Did you modify it after creating it?

Comment: Did you create the ForeignKey first and then modify the `id` field afterwards to be BigAutoField?

Comment: Yes I modified the data type after creating it.. I ended up using raw sql to change the type.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove default auto field and use [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield) instead by naming [primary_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) field

```
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Yes that is how I have the primary key now.. but foreign keys I cant change the data type.